# Need help to configure Resource Adapter in Jboss EAP 6.4

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, jboss6.x, jboss-eap-6

I am doing jboss migration from Jboss4.x to Jboss 6.4 and current version Jboss 4.x configured connection factories to communicate mainframe and working so I try to doing same thing to migrate Jboss 6 configuration using resource adapter. But I getting exception(). I do not know what I am missing.

**Current JBoss 4.x configuration**

**jracappstest-ds.xml**

```
<connection-factories>
                <no-tx-connection-factory>

                <jndi-name>eis/JracRa/AppslinkTest</jndi-name>
                <rar-name>unisys-jrac-connector-3.0.0.rar</rar-name>

                <connection-definition>
                    javax.resource.cci.ConnectionFactory
                </connection-definition>

                <config-property name="ServerName" type="java.lang.String">
                    TEST
                </config-property>
                <config-property name="PortNumber" type="java.lang.String">
                    6666
                </config-property>
                <config-property name="WindowName" type="java.lang.String">
                    TEST_NAME
                </config-property>

                <security-domain>jca-credentials</security-domain>

                <idle-timeout-minutes>20</idle-timeout-minutes>

                <min-pool-size>2</min-pool-size>
                <max-pool-size>10</max-pool-size>

            </no-tx-connection-factory>
        </connection-factories>
```

**Exception**

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: eis/JracRa/AppsTest -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.eis.JracRa.AppsTest
        at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:104)
        at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:197)
        at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:174)
        at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext$DefaultInitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:245)
        at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:183)
        at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:179)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at com.myapp.utils.unisys.connection.MainframeRA.lookupConnectionFactory(MainframeRA.java:292) [mainframe-ra-2.2.0.jar:]
        at com.myapp.utils.unisys.connection.MainframeRA.initializeConnectionFactory(MainframeRA.java:249) [mainframe-ra-2.2.0.jar:]
        ... 41 more
```

**Code**

```
private ConnectionFactory lookupConnectionFactory()
        throws NamingException {

        final Context initContext = new InitialContext();
        final String jndiName = "java:jboss/"
            + UnisysDataSource.getInstance().lookupJndiName(targetRegionValue);
        return (onnectionFactory) initContext.lookup(jndiName);

    }
```

**configured in standalone.xml**

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:1.1">

            <resource-adapters>

                <resource-adapter id="unisys-jrac-connector-3.0.0.rar">

                    <archive>
                        unisys-jrac-connector-3.0.0.rar
                    </archive>

                    <transaction-support>NoTransaction</transaction-support>

                    <connection-definitions>
                        <connection-definition class-name="javax.resource.cci.ConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:jboss/eis/JracRa/AppsTest" use-java-context="true" pool-name="eis/JracRa/AppsTest">

                            <config-property name="UserName">
                                TEST
                            </config-property>
                            <config-property name="WindowName">
                                TEST_NAME
                            </config-property>
                            <config-property name="PortNumber">
                                6666
                            </config-property>
                            <config-property name="ServerName">
                                server_name
                            </config-property>
                            <config-property name="Password">
                                TEST_PASS
                            </config-property>
                        </connection-definition>

                </resource-adapter>

            </resource-adapters>

 </subsystem>
```